# 'import type' declaration failing during build in nextjs project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, babeljs, syntax-error

I'm unable to import the `Metadata` type from the `next` module.

The below code is taken directly from the Next.js docs.

**THE ERROR**

```
client.js:1 ./app/layout.tsx:3:12
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "from"

1 | import React from 'react';
2 | import './globals.css';

> 3 | import type { Metadata } from 'next';
> |             ^
> 4 | import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
> 5 |
> 6 | const inter = Inter({ subsets: \['latin'\] });
```

**app/layout.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import './globals.css';
import type { Metadata } from 'next';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Play Chopsticks',
  description:
    'Some call it finger chess, some call it magic fingers. Test you skills and become the number one chopsticks master',
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**// tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["./components/*"],
      "@/app/*": ["./app/*"]
    },
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I'm unsure if my `tsconfig.json` is correct. It excludes 'node _modules' directory. However the 'next' module is inside the `node_modules`

Answer (score 0):

**I figured it out:**

In my project folder I had a `.babelrc` file.
*Having this `.babelrc` file apparently automatically 'opts out' from using the 'Nextjs compiler'.*

The 'Nextjs Compiler' must be important for compiling the typescript imports from the 'next' module.

Sooo, I deleted the `.babelrc` file aaaand viola... compilation success! #*insert Borat here*#

I'm unsure of exactly how or why it works, but that solved it...
If anyone knows more please enlighten us with your insight!